# BlueZ , set connection interval

Tags: connection, intervals, bluez

I'm trying to speed up communication that uses iOS on one end and BlueZ on the arm linux platform at the other end.
What I have realized so far is that bluez api does not have the option to change the connect event.
My wish is to set from the default 30mS to 15mS and thus speed up the communication.
I'm trying to ect/bluetooth/main.conf, but I'm not sure if this is the right way to go. Please if anyone can offer me the best way to do this also via hci commands or bluetoothctl?

Comment: It seems that you have entered the wrong Nexus of the Metaverse :-) Over there at SE [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/458056) answer was given.

Answer (score 2):

This is done as a driver config, if you have debugfs enabled:

```
echo "30" > /sys/kernel/debug/bluetooth/hci0/conn_min_interval
echo "45" > /sys/kernel/debug/bluetooth/hci0/conn_max_interval
```

Take into consideration the Apple Guideline for optimal results: https://developer.apple.com/accessories/Accessory-Design-Guidelines.pdf (page 180 - 40.6 Connection Parameters).

Comment: This id HCI settings , but how to put connect interval as attribute inside GATT?

Comment: The Linux Bluetooth stack provides access to the BLE connection interval
min and max values through /sys/kernel/debug/bluetooth/hci0/
conn_min_interval and /sys/kernel/debug/bluetooth/hci0/conn_max_interval.